# so i want to close the multiprocessing when the gui is closed so i wrote this

Tags: python, multiprocessing

in main.py

```
class Persona():
def __init__(self):
    self.ex = True

    def gui():
       self.ex = False
            
    gui()
```

in driver.py

```
#p1 = mp.Process(target=player)
#p2 = mp.Process(target=Persona)

def main():

            #p1.start()
            #p2.start()
            #i want to make this code keep checking while p2 processing
            checker = Persona().ex
            if checker == False:
                    #p1.terminate()
                    #p2.terminate()

            



if __name__ == '__main__':
           main()
```

but it seems it doesnt work even though i closed the gui, basically i want the gui() to update the state of self.ex when i run it so it will terminate the p1 and p2 (because when self.ex = false it terminates them)

Is there any way to keep the code checking the process of p2 while its still running?

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. The above code never calls `gui()`, so it proably doesn't represent your actual code. Make sure you can copy'n'paste the code into a file and run that! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Im sorry i'll make sure to rewrite them

Comment: You can't specify `p2 = mp.Process(target=Persona)` because `Persona` is a class and not a function. And your indentation is wrong. Please don't post approximations of code. If you were to make `p1` a *daemon* process and then have the `p1` process terminate by itself when the GUI is closed, then there would be no need for any checking by anyone; the daemon process would automatically terminate when there were no more non-daemon processes running.

Comment: Let me correct what I said about daemon processes. Daemon processes will automatically terminate when the main process terminates. So make `p1` a daemon process with `p1 = mp.Process(target=player, daemon=True)` and have the main process wait for the completion of `p2` by calling `p2.join()`, which should then end when the the GUI is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that main thread only checks to see if `checker == False` once and then it is done.  It has no reason to check it over and over.

You need to use a `multiprocessing.Event` to coordinate between your main thread and the GUI.  the GUI will call `gui_terminated.set()`, where `gui_terminated` is an Event, when it is finished.  Your main thread will call `gui_terminated.wait()`.

From your code, it is not clear if the gui is a separate process.  If it is, you should pass `gui_terminated` as an argument to it.  That is the safest way to share events between processes.